# iOS:How to change the pictures in a video?

Tags: ios, video, uiimage, avfoundation

I need to change the pictures into animation video, but I don't known how to make a video, do not know to have what good method?

Comment: This link will be useful, [create-movie-from-array-of-images](http://ios.biomsoft.com/2012/02/01/create-movie-from-array-of-images/)

Comment: They're called "frames", not "pictures".

Answer (score 0):

for example make your image names as xxxx-1.png, xxxx-2.png ......  xxxx-80.png. and paste the below code.. then the images will animate like video.

```
NSMutableArray* imgArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (int i=1; i <= 80; i++) {
            [imgArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"xxxx-%d.png",i]]];
        }
    UIImageView* imgView = [UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:(x,y,a,b)];
    imgView.animationImages = imgArray;
    imgView.animationDuration = 0.25;
    imgView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [imgView startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
    [imgView release];
```

Comment: thank you,but I want make the UIImageView to a video..how to make a video?